# Grid does not fit the screen on Xiaomi

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a somewhat unusual problem and I did not find any references in the searches I performed.

I have a Xamarin Forms application and on the login screen the Grid does not adjust to the layout and does not display any controls on the screen.

To make it easier to understand, I made the screen as simple as possible by replacing the background image with a solid color one.

I've already changed the login screen several times, but it didn't work. I've tried with the Grid, without the Grid, Grid with lines, Grid without lines, a Stacklayout for each line of the Grid, a single Stacklayout, with Frame, without Frame, but nothing solves.

And the worst thing is that in the tests done by the robot on firebase, they found no errors.

This only happens on some Xiaomi (on other devices, even Xiaomi, it doesn't).

I'm using VS 2019 and Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.1269.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MySample.Controls"
BackgroundImage="solid.png"
x:Class="MySample.Views.LoginView">

<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,20,0,0" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Padding>

<ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid x:Name="gridExterno" 
          RowSpacing="0" 
          ColumnSpacing="0" 
          Padding="30,20,30,5" 
          BackgroundColor="White"
          Margin="30,5"  
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center">

        <Grid.MinimumHeightRequest>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="600" Phone="300" Desktop="300"/>
        </Grid.MinimumHeightRequest>

        <Grid.MinimumWidthRequest>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="800" Phone="600"  Desktop="600"/>
        </Grid.MinimumWidthRequest>

        <Grid.WidthRequest>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="800" Phone="600"  Desktop="600"/>
        </Grid.WidthRequest>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="logo.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,10,0,10">
            <Image.WidthRequest>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="350" Phone="300" Desktop="300"/>
            </Image.WidthRequest>
        </Image>

        <StackLayout 
                Orientation="Vertical"
                Grid.Row="1"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                Spacing="15" 
                Margin="10">

            <Entry x:Name="EntryLogin" 
                       TextChanged="OnEntryLoginTextChanged"
                       MaxLength="20"
                       Text=""
                       Keyboard="Numeric"  
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Entry.WidthRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="400" Phone="300" Desktop="300"/>
                </Entry.WidthRequest>

                <Entry.HeightRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="75" Phone="50" Desktop="50"/>
                </Entry.HeightRequest>

                <Entry.Margin>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Tablet="0,0,0,20" Phone="0" Desktop="0"/>
                </Entry.Margin>

                <Entry.FontSize>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="30" Phone="20" Desktop="20" />
                </Entry.FontSize>
            </Entry>

            <Entry x:Name="EntryPassword" 
                        Text=""
                        MaxLength="20"
                        IsPassword="True" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Entry.Margin>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Tablet="0,0,0,20" Phone="0" Desktop="0"/>
                </Entry.Margin>

                <Entry.WidthRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="400" Phone="300" Desktop="300"/>
                </Entry.WidthRequest>

                <Entry.HeightRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="75" Phone="50" Desktop="50"/>
                </Entry.HeightRequest>

                <Entry.FontSize>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="28" Phone="20" Desktop="20"/>
                </Entry.FontSize>
            </Entry>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="16" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout.Margin>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Tablet="2,0" Phone="0"  Desktop="0"/>
                </StackLayout.Margin>

                <CheckBox x:Name="ckRemember"/>

                <Label Text="Remember Me" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label.FontSize>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="26" Phone="18"  Desktop="18"/>
                    </Label.FontSize>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <Button  x:Name="btnEntrar1" 
                                Text="Enter" 
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ButtonPrimary}" 
                                Clicked="OnLoginAsync"
                                TextColor="White" 
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Button.WidthRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="400" Phone="300" Desktop="300"/>
                </Button.WidthRequest>

                <Button.HeightRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="75" Phone="50" Desktop="50"/>
                </Button.HeightRequest>

                <Button.FontSize>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="18" />
                </Button.FontSize>

                <Button.Margin>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Tablet="0,15,0,0" Phone="0"  Desktop="0"/>
                </Button.Margin>
            </Button>

            <Label x:Name="lblVersion" 
                VerticalOptions="End" 
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center">

                <Label.FontSize>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="20" Phone="16" Desktop="16"/>
                </Label.FontSize>

                <Label.Margin>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Tablet="0,0,0,10" Phone="0,3,0,5"  Desktop="0,3,0,5"/>
                </Label.Margin>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: If you are not providing details/context with a [mre] it is very hard for people to help you at best it will be guesses.

Comment: how can we possibly help you debug this when you haven't posted any code or xaml?

Comment: Added more info

Comment: @WashingtonMorais I test your code at xiaomi Mi Note LTE (Android 6.0) and Android 9.0 emulator, it works fine, Grid can display successfully.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Yes, me too, but I have several users sending a print screen of their phones showing this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `x:Name="gridExterno"` HorizontalOptions to `HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"`